# Cache configuration ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching

I am trying to understand the cache configuration below:

```
<!--Configures expiration for files in CMS/VPP-->
<staticFile expirationTime="12:0:0" />

<!--Configures expiration in IIS-->
<system.webServer>
   <!--Configures client headers for static files from IIS-->
   <staticContent>
       <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="1.00:00:00"></clientCache>
   </staticContent>
   <!--Configures output and kernel caching for ALL images (both CMS and IIS)-->
   <caching>
      <profiles>
        <add extension=".gif" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" duration="0.00:01:00" location="Any" />
        <add extension=".png" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" duration="0.00:01:00" location="Any" />
        <add extension=".js" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" duration="0.00:01:00" location="Any" />
        <add extension=".css" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" duration="0.00:01:00" location="Any" />
        <add extension=".jpg" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" duration="0.00:01:00" location="Any" />
        <add extension=".jpeg" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" duration="0.00:01:00" location="Any" />
      </profiles>
   </caching>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

So the static files will be cached for 1 day as the cacheControlMaxAge="1.00:00:00". But I am confused as to why we have:

```
<staticFile expirationTime="12:0:0" />
```

And also the mime types have an expiration of 1 minute:

```
<caching>
      <profiles>
        <add extension=".gif" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" duration="0.00:01:00" location="Any" />
        <add extension=".png" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" duration="0.00:01:00" location="Any" />
        <add extension=".js" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" duration="0.00:01:00" location="Any" />
        <add extension=".css" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" duration="0.00:01:00" location="Any" />
        <add extension=".jpg" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" duration="0.00:01:00" location="Any" />
        <add extension=".jpeg" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" duration="0.00:01:00" location="Any" />
      </profiles>
   </caching>
```

So does it mean that all static content is cached for 1 day or is it specific to the settings? Like any files other than the mime types is 1 day and the mime types are 1 minute.

Answer (score 1):

`<staticFile>` is non-standard. That appears to be a configuration element for [EPiServer.Web.StaticFileHandler](https://support.episerver.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004100483-Set-staticFile-Configuration-in-web-config-to-Ensure-Latest-Media-Files-Retrieved-Client-Side). `<system.webServer>` is configuring IIS. Which configuration is used depends on what module is handling the request.

The documentation over at https://learn.microsoft.com is pretty good: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/staticcontent/clientcache

Besides this I would say there's no better way to find out what it does / what configuration matters than to give it a try. On most browsers you can press F12 and open the [developer tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/). Make a request to the static files and look at the Network tab. Read the response headers, such as Cache-Control, Last-Modified, etc.